# Google App Engine Task Queue REST API for the Java Development Server (devserver)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-api-java-client, task-queue

I have a GAE app running on the Java Development Server (AKA devserver) on my local machine that defines some Task Queue pull queues.

I want to use the Task Queue REST API from a different standalone Java app, running on my machine, to access these pull queues.

I tried [the sample](https://github.com/google/google-api-java-client-samples/tree/master/taskqueue-cmdline-sample) suggested by Google's [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/rest/libraries) that implements leasing tasks. Apparently, it uses the [Google API Client Library for Java](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/) that requires a `client_secrets.json` file of the format:

```
{
  "installed": {
    "client_id": "retrieved from creating a Service Account for the project",
    "client_secret": "supposedly appears in the JSON file that's downloaded upon creation of a Service Account for the project"
  }
}
```

I created a Service Account for the project and a JSON was automatically downloaded, with the following format:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "myProjectId",
  "private_key_id": "some long hexadecimal",
  "private_key": "an even longer encrypted stuff",
  "client_email": "myServiceAccountName@myProjectId.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "a decimal number",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/myServiceAccountName%40myProjectId.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

In my `client_secrets.json` file I used `private_key_id` as the `client_secret` value and executed the sample code.

The result was that it opened `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth` in my browser, which displayed an error with status code `400` and the following message:

> Error: redirect_uri_mismatch Application: My Application The redirect
>   URI in the request: http://localhost:61130/Callback did not match a
>   registered redirect URI.

I tried `Taskqueue.Builder.setRootUrl("http://localhost:8080")`, although its javadoc says not to mess with it. It returned `401 Unauthorized`.

1. Is there a way to use the Task Queue REST API from a standalone Java app to access these pull queues? I prefer using the Java libraries offered by Google but apparently they automatically point to the actual GAE services.
2. What should I use as the value of `client_secret`<sup>1</sup> in the `client_secrets.json` file when I do want to lease tasks from Google App Engine on the cloud?

---

<sup><sup>1</sup> When I created the Service Account, since I'm not the owner of the project, I got the following message:</sup>

> <sup>The service account could not be added to this project's permissions
>   because you are not an owner of the project. To give the service
>   account access to this project, ask a project owner to add it to the
>   project permissions.</sup>

<sup>I wonder whether this has something to do with the absence of a `client_secret` property in the automatically downloaded JSON.</sup>

Comment: Wow 6 hours and 3 views, not too much people using Task Queue REST API... No wonder, if you can't easily develop with it on your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think the dev server will expose the Task Queue API, do your tests against a separate test project that you create.
2. You can use the JSON from the service account to connect to the Task Queue API, see [service accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) documentation.

   GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("MyProject-1234.json"))
       .createScoped(Collections.singleton("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/taskqueue"));

   Taskqueue taskQueue = new Taskqueue.Builder(
       httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential).setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
       .setTaskqueueRequestInitializer(new TaskqueueRequestInitializer() {
         @Override
         public void initializeTaskqueueRequest(TaskqueueRequest request) {
           request.setPrettyPrint(true);
         }
       }).build();

   // get queue

   com.google.api.services.taskqueue.model.TaskQueue queue = getQueue(taskQueue);
   System.out.println(queue);

   // lease, execute and delete tasks

   Tasks tasks = getLeasedTasks(taskQueue);